# Google Compute Engine - Where is the STOPPED instance status?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Yesterday I tried to delete an Instance by invoking the "halt" command through SSH. Unlike AWS, GCE does not allow us to choose the behavior of the VM shutdown and stop the instance by default (the instance status is TERMINATED).

Today I was browsing the [Google Compute Engine REST API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances#resource) and I found the following description :

> status : [Output Only] The status of the instance. One of the following values: PROVISIONING, STAGING, RUNNING, STOPPING, STOPPED, TERMINATED.

What is this "STOPPPED" status ? Both the instances stopped through the Web console or the "halt" command have the "TERMINATED" status.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

This STOPPED state is a new feature added a few weeks ago which you can reach [via the compute engine API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/stop).

> This method stops a running instance, shutting it down cleanly, and allows you to restart the instance at a later time. Stopped instances do not incur per-minute, virtual machine usage charges while they are stopped, but any resources that the virtual machine is using, such as persistent disks and static IP addresses,will continue to be charged until they are deleted. For more information, see Stopping an instance.

I think this is similar to the AWS option you mention.

Comment: I saw this explanation in the documentation, nevertheless the instance state is still "TERMINATED". Maybe this new state will be introduced in the next days.

Comment: Did you use the `halt` command from inside the VM, or select "stop" from the UI or `gcloud` tool?

Comment: All of them. And all give the "STOPPED" status.

Comment: This answer looks outdated, the linked documentation does not mention a "STOPPED" status anymore

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling on this question years later, a detailed lifecycle diagram of instances can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/instance-life-cycle)

There is no `STOPPED` status anymore, instances are going from `STOPPING` to `TERMINATED`, whatever the stopping method is.

However a new state, that may be closer to what `halt` does, has been introduced since: `SUSPENDED`. It's still in beta though, and not sure that invoking `halt` would induce this state or simply terminates the instance.
See [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/instance-life-cycle) for more details